# Script for email alert and ping

Tags: bash, email

I need help to update this script to if ping fails it would send another ping to another host (besides the email which is sent now if ping fails).
How can this be done from this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="IP ADRESS"
COUNT=4

for myHost in $HOSTS
do
    count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | a$
    if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
        # 100% failed
        echo "Server failed at $(date)" | mail -s "Server Down" myadress@gmail.com
        echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
    fi
done
```

Comment: what is the question here ? do you want the mail sent if both fail ?

Comment: @Sorin. I like to get a mail if IP1 fails, and then i was thinking that IP2 get a ping <and starts up with wol>.I belive that this doesnt work because it need to use wakeonlan+MAC, not just a ping. Or can this be done with just ping?? So if wakonland command needs to be used instead: IP1 fails get a mail - IP2 gets "wakonlan 1:2:3:4:5:6" and starts up. Just need to get mail if IP1 fails...

Answer (score 5):

You can put the `ping` stuff in a function. You do not need to process (`grep`) the `ping` result: you can rely on `ping` return exit status.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="IP1 IP2 IP3 IP4 IP5"
COUNT=4

pingtest(){
  for myHost in "$@"
  do
    ping -c "$COUNT" "$myHost" && return 1
  done
  return 0
}

if pingtest $HOSTS
then
  # 100% failed
  echo "Server failed at $(date)" | mail -s "Server Down" myadress@gmail.com
  echo "All hosts ($HOSTS) are down (ping failed) at $(date)"
fi
```

Comment: Ok i will try this, thanx. Do i understand it correctly that if IP1 and IP2 fails it will send a ping to IP3 and if that one is up it stops there?

Comment: All right, you have understood the script ;-)   Do not forget to up vote the answer :-D

Comment: @oHessling Did you try this out? As far as I see, at least echoing `$myHost` fails, as that's a local variable. And if you do a return in the `for` loop, the next IP will never be pinged.

Comment: @oHessing. I did try it after getting wol to work properly. Its seems that that my original thought that if IP1 fails IP2 would start with wol doensent work with just ping (i cant get it to wok anyway). When i run command wakeonlan+MAC i can get IP2 to start up. So next question is how to set IP2 in the script to get "wakeonlan+MAC" and start up if ping to IP1 fails?

Comment: Hi @ViktorKuznyetso. I am not sure about what you want (ping IP2 on IP1 failure, and then ping IP1 after IP2 failure...???). The best for your second question, is to edit this current question (add your new requirements) OR to create a new question. Unfortunately, StackOverflow (SO) is not designed as a forum: we can chat online on SO but we cannot continue discussion within these comments. If you decide to create a new question, then please do not forget to UP vote my answer and validate it, thanks.

Comment: Hi @ZsoltBotykai. Please undo your down vote. I have tested again my initial script, and the least `echo $myHost` was OK because the function `pingtest` uses it as a global variable within the `bash` script. Then I rollbacked to the initial tiny script. But I removed `$myHost` because it has no sense any more: all the `$HOSTS` failed (not just `$myHost`). Cheers.

Answer (score -3):

Try this with an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS_ARRAY=("IP_ADRESS" "ANOTHER_IP" "YET_ANOTHER")
COUNT=4
for myHost in "${HOSTS_ARRAY[@]}"
do
     count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | a$
     if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
         # 100% failed
         echo "Server failed at $(date)" | mail -s "Server Down" myadress@gmail.com
         echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
     fi
done
```

Comment: @ZsoitBotykai Using an array will not fix his issue: `for myHost in $HOSTS` is correct.

Comment: Trying to understand.If the first "IP_ADRESS" fails does it send a ping to "ANOTHER_IP" then? What happens if there is a IP on "YET_ANOTHER"?

Comment: If `IP_ADDRESS` failed it will print the lines you wanted. Then it sets the `$myHost` variable to the next IP in hte array. Then pings it. Whatever happens it loops throug each element in the array.